# React native does not give error on undefined variables

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

In react native, I've noticed that undefined variables do not give an error. Instead, execution just quietly halts at the undefined variable. This makes development slower. Is there any way to get a more explicit error? I have `'use strict;'` at the top of my file, but that does not seem to help with this

EDIT:

Example of a failure:

```
      <Text style={{fontWeight: bold}}>Apply flow</Text>
```

In this case, `bold` should actually be `'bold'`. I would expect an undefined variable exception, but instead my app just silently fails on this line.

Comment: Can you use an example that you have run across?

Comment: An exception will be thrown when an undefined variable is referenced like this. Maybe the render is happening within a try-catch block that is silently discarding caught exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening on your project, but I just tried this and got:

[image]

In the Xcode console I see: "message: Can't find variable: bold". This is with React Native 0.6.0.